# A grid da Kendo tem limitador de linhas?

Tags: kendo-ui

Estou usando a Kendo Grid para mostrar pro usuário mais de 6000 linhas, porém quando eu mando no datasource mais de 1500 registros, ela não carrega... simplesmente não mostra nenhum registro. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Tem a certeza que quer fazer isso? 6000 linhas consome muitos recursos (muito html e muito tráfego de dados). Uma solucao melhor poderá ser enviar um documento excel ou pdf para o cliente.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Sim, eu preciso trazer estes dados, realmente consome muitos recursos... tanto que o problema não é da Kendo, mas sim da conexão que não estava dando conta do recado. Obrigada!

Comment: [uma pergunta na comunidade inglesa que pode ajudar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9943727)

Comment: Obrigada @BrunoCosta, mas já resolvi... o problema é só na minha máquina... como eu conecto num servidor fora do país, e a minha conexão está lenta, o servidor não me devolve os dados. Mas em ambiente de homologação funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Use virtualização da grid para tantas linhas...

Answer (score 1):

A Kendo não tem limitadores, o problema se dava em função do consumo de recursos. Foi identificado que no ambiente de desenvolvimento, não funcionava, mas em homologação o problema não ocorria.